# why adding extra button tag in ng-select2 drop down list

Tags: angular, angular8, jquery-select2, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to add button a in `ng-Select2` dropdown.

I need to add html in their `templateResult` property with definition as how your list would show.

If I add a `<span>` or `<div>` it is working fine. However if I add `<button>` then it is adding an extra button tag.
How can I remove this extra button?

**html**

```
<ng-select2
   class="form-item select2"
   name="clientGroup"
   placeholder="select client group"
   [(ngModel)]="client.clientGroupID"
   #clientGroup="ngModel"
   [options]="optionsClientGroup"
   [data]="clientGroups"
   required>
</ng-select2>
```

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getClientGroups();
    this.optionsClientGroup = {
      templateResult: this.templateResult,
    };
}

getClientGroups() {
    this.subs = this.clientService.getClientGroups().subscribe((res) => {
      res.responseModel.forEach((clientGroup) => {
        this.clientGroups.push({
          id: clientGroup['id'],
          text: clientGroup['clientGroupName'],
        });
      });
      this.clientGroups.push({
        id: '1233',
        text: 'button',
        additional: { html: '<button >Add New Client Group<button>' },
      });
    });
}

public clientTemplateResult = (state: any): JQuery | string => {
    if (state.additional && state.additional.html)
      return jQuery(state.additional.html);
    else {
      jQuery(state.text);
    }
};
```

Here what I get in drop down:
[result image][1]

Here what I get when I inspect the page:

```
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--selectable select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-uazh-result-fe1t-1233" role="option" data-select2-id="select2-data-select2-uazh-result-fe1t-1233" aria-selected="true">
<button>Add New Client Group</button>
<button></button>
</li>
```

Comment: We don't see the image